# iPad frozen after long pressing an app icon

Tags: ipad, ios

I have an iPad 2 with iOS 9. I wanted to uninstall / remove an app, so I long press the app icon. The icon started to wiggle, but the problem is the iPad no longer respond to any input. Tap, swipe, pressing the home button, pressing the power button, they don't change anything on the iPad. The iPad stayed on the same screen with the wiggling icons. After some time, the screen went black showing the apple logo, and then the lock screen showed and I can access the iPad.

Is there a workaround for deleting an app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Settings - General - Storage - Manage Storage find the app and delete from there.